# How to validate regex-field using JSON schema

Tags: .net, json, jsonschema

For example I have JSON with field NameRegex:

```
{
   "NameRegex": ".*abc+"
}
```

users constantly forget "." before "*" or make similar mistakes. Is it possible to validate correctness of regex specified in this field using json schema?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no good way to validate a regex since almost any string (even this answer) could be a valid regex.  Even if you had a good way, regex validation would be implementation-based and disjoint from the requirements of JSON Schema.  My implementation (in .Net), for instance, delgates regex processing to the `Regex` class.  If it fails, then you'll get a run-time exception.

The best you can realistically do is extensively test your regex before deployment into production.

Here are a couple good testing sites:

- https://www.regexpal.com/  This is the one I most often use
- https://regex101.com/  Breaks down the regex and explain each part

There are plenty of others as well.

Comment: No, `*abc+` is not a valid regex since there is nothing to repeat before the `*`

Comment: @erikkallen I've expanded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using the JSON schema, but you can do it in code, by hooking into the deserialization process. There you will verify that the NameRegex string is a valid regular expression by trying to construct a Regex object from it, and throw an exception if not valid.

To do this,  create a validation method that takes a StreamingContext in the target class, and decorate it with the  [OnDeserialized] attribute.  Write your validation code in that method.  For example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string NameRegex { get; set; }

  [OnDeserialized]
  internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
  {
    try
    {
      //ensure NameRegex is a valid regex
      var r = new Regex(NameRegex);
    }
    catch
    {
      //throw whatever exception is appropriate for you
      throw new InvalidDataException(
         $"'{NameRegex}' is not a valid regular expression.");
    }
  }  
}
```

Deserializing will throw the exception you defined if the validation fails:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
  @"{""NameRegex"":""abc+""}",
  typeof(Foo));
```

**** NameRegex value '*abc+' is not a valid regular expression ****

Answer (score 0):

JSON schema has an annotation keyword `format` that some validators also validate (this is optional per the specification).

So you could say:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "NameRegex": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "regex"
        }
    }
}
```

but it's not required for validators to validate "format" keywords. And as Greg mentioned, often the regex is still valid even if you omit the dot in front of the `*`; it just has a different meaning (repeating whatever character was in front of the star, rather than any character, zero or more times)

It's still a good idea to use the `format` keyword though, as at least it's good documentation of your intention for the property, even if your particular validator doesn't validate formats.